# CSS ellipsis inside the container with undetermined width

Tags: html, css

I have a problem styling a cell in the AG Grid table.
This cell can have a various width, depending on the screen size.
Inside the cell, I want to store:

1. left-aligned text that should be truncated (ellipsed) when there's no space left
2. after (1), a text in a wrapper that has exactly 40px width

The problem I encountered is that ellipses property often doesn't work. I noticed I cannot use calc() to mimic fixed width. Essentially, I want to style the cell to look like this, for short text:
[image],
and like this:
[image] for long text.

Unfortunately, I am struggling with making the "40px text" to render right after the 1st block of text. To keep ellipsis property working, I am stuck at this result:

[image]

I know I cannot use the grid layout here 'cause it won't allow me to have '40 px text' occur right after 1st block of text but it's the closes I got to the end result.
"cell-root", "cell-wrapper", "cell-inner-container" are predefined by ag-grid but I can access and modify their styling. Everything nested inside 'cell-inner-container' is my custom code and can be freely removed, changed or added.

Could somebody help me out figuring out the correct css for this thing?
Working sample attached to the topic, but also accessible here: https://codepen.io/whichmann/pen/ZEqOxLq

```css
.long-example {
  left: 98px;
  top: 120px;
}

.short-example {
  top: 50px;
  left: 98px;
}

.cell-root {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 12px;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 187px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 40px;
}

.cell-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
}

.cell-inner-container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border-right: 2px solid green;
}

.custom-cell-wrapper {
/*  display: flex; */
/*  flex-direction: row; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  border-bottom: 2px solid pink;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper-for-long-text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-left: 2px dotted blue;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper-for-fixed-width-text {
  line-height: unset;
  color: blue;
  padding-left: 4px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div>
"position" and "width" property in .cell-root cannot be changed. <br />
"cell-root", "cell-wrapper", "cell-inner-container" are predefined by ag-grid but I can access and modify their styling.
</div>

<div class="cell-root long-example">
  <div class="cell-wrapper">
    <span class="cell-inner-container">
      <div class=custom-cell-wrapper>
        <span class="wrapper-for-long-text">
          long text that is too long
        </span>
        <div class="wrapper-for-fixed-width-text">40 px text</div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cell-root short-example">
  <div class="cell-wrapper">
    <span class="cell-inner-container">
      <div class=custom-cell-wrapper>
        <span class="wrapper-for-long-text">
          short text
        </span>
        <div class="wrapper-for-fixed-width-text">40 px text</div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close – you can use `flex` rather than `grid` on `.custom-cell-wrapper`, but need to force `width: 100%` on `.cell-wrapper` and `.cell-inner-container` so that they don't overflow on the long input.

Can also remove the overflow rules on `.custom-cell-wrapper` because the ellipses should appear on `.wrapper-for-long-text`.

```css
.long-example {
  left: 98px;
  top: 120px;
}

.short-example {
  top: 50px;
  left: 98px;
}

.cell-root {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 12px;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 187px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 40px;
}

.cell-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
}

.cell-inner-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border-right: 2px solid green;
}

.custom-cell-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 2px solid pink;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper-for-long-text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-left: 2px dotted blue;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper-for-fixed-width-text {
  line-height: unset;
  color: blue;
  padding-left: 4px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div>
"position" and "width" property in .cell-root cannot be changed. <br />
"cell-root", "cell-wrapper", "cell-inner-container" are predefined by ag-grid but I can access and modify their styling.
</div>

<div class="cell-root long-example">
  <div class="cell-wrapper">
    <span class="cell-inner-container">
      <div class=custom-cell-wrapper>
        <span class="wrapper-for-long-text">
          long text that is too long
        </span>
        <div class="wrapper-for-fixed-width-text">40 px text</div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cell-root short-example">
  <div class="cell-wrapper">
    <span class="cell-inner-container">
      <div class=custom-cell-wrapper>
        <span class="wrapper-for-long-text">
          short text
        </span>
        <div class="wrapper-for-fixed-width-text">40 px text</div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm! I could have sworn I've tried setting the width to 100%. Probably didn't try to apply it to both parent containers. Spot on, thanks!